# we have vector $a$ and $b$,$||a|| = 6$, $||b|| = 3$, find the largest and smallest value of $||a-b||$ and $a^Tb$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces

Here is my prove

in $180°$ the largest will $||a-b||$ would be $||a|| + ||b||$ equal to $9$

In $0°$ the line will overlap, so it would be $||a|| - ||b||$ equal to $3$

Therefore, $3 ≤ ||a-b|| ≤ 9$

And for the $a^Tb$

$cosθ = a^Tb/||a|| ||b||$;
for the $cosθ = -1$, $a^Tb = -18$
for the $cosθ = 1$, $a^Tb = 18$
So the $-18 ≤ a^Tb ≤ 18$

Do I prove it correct?

Comment: Yes, roughly. To improve the exposition, state what is the angle that you are talking about. Show the formula relating $a^Tb$ and $\cos(\theta)$, such that it is clear why you are considering those values of $\cos(\theta)$.

Comment: If you want to be fancy, you can invoke the triangle inequality $|a+b| \le |a| + |b|$ and $|a-b| \ge ||a|-|b||$ and Cauchy-Schwartz,$ |\langle a,b\rangle| \le |a||b|$